# SQLite: How to check if there is another row of data without moving cursor?

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to find out if there is another row of data available after a "select" query without moving the cursor by calling "sqlite3_step" again?

Comment: can you post the code you have so we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: I doubt there is. SQLite queries are miniature programs; calling `sqlite3_step` resumes execution of the programs. There's no general way to determine if a program will have more output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite computes the output rows dynamically, when needed.

So it is not possible to find out if you can get another row without actually trying to step to that row.

Comment: Ok thanks, couldn't find in documentation but figured it didn't hurt to ask.